# Google Data Studio: Day of Week Showing as Interger, Not Day Name

Tags: looker-studio

Monday to Sunday shows as 1 - 7 in my report. Is it possible to show Day Names instead?

I have used this calculate field to get the "WEEKDAY" but it presents me with day numbers:

```
WEEKDAY(Date)
```

Answer (score 7):

The [FORMAT_DATETIME](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334#) function can format dates in a variety of different ways. In this case, you'll want to use `%A` which is the full weekday name.

`FORMAT_DATETIME("%A", Date)`

Comment: Doesn't work. Displays the weekday in number.